# I want to show two different alerts on one method and one form

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ajaxform

I have only one form for update and create and one  button in this form. I want when I will click on submit button then alert will must show automatically update or create that alert which i will get request through controller. I am not able to use data-ajax call. So tell me about how I will show-ajax call. or give me a sample of this and this is my code and help me about this.

```
<form id="blogForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="AddBlog" method="post">
    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="blogRequestDTO.Id" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="blogRequestDTO.Title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="blogRequestDTO.Title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter blog name">
            <span asp-validation-for="blogRequestDTO.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- For Image-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="blogRequestDTO.Image" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input asp-for="blogRequestDTO.Image" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="blogRequestDTO.Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to use onclick to call ajax when submitting.

Below is my test code you can refer to it.

```
@model Project.Models.blogRequestDTO

<form id="blogForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddBlog" method="post">
    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" id="Id" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="Title" asp-for="@Model.Title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter blog name">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- For Image-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Image" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input id="Image" asp-for="@Model.Image" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Test()" type="submit" >submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function Test()
    {
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("Id", $("#Id").val());
        formData.append("Title",$("#Title").val());
        formData.append("Image",$("#Image")[0].files[0]);
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/AddBlog',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (response, error) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```